# Where did the 'adaptive' check go in the subsurface modifier from 2.80, in 2.81?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Where did the 'adaptive' check go in the subsurface modifier from 2.80, in 2.81?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you haven't set the *Feature Set* to *Experimental* in the *Render Properties*.

Comment: sorry, I'm new. I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adaptive subdivision feature is only available when you use the *Cycles* render engine and set the *Feature Set* to [*Experimental*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/features.html) in the *Render Properties*.

[image: Feature Set]

Once the experimental feature set is enabled you will see the additional panel for the subdivision settings in the render properties and the subdivision surface modifier will have the options as shown in your screenshot.

[image: Subdivision panel]

[image: New options in the subdivision modifier]

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't ask enough questions here, so I can't upvote your answer. :(

Comment: @Shakaama If my answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.